# Remove specific HTML elements in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I have seen whitelist based sanitizers for HTML in Ruby, but I need the opposite, I need ONLY links removed from a page to be readied for PDF conversion. I tried Sanitize, but it does not fit what I need as it is too difficult to guess what HTML elements will be used on the fetched page, so that I can add them to the list.

If my input was

```
<a href="link">Link!</a>
<b>Bold Text</b>
<div>A div!</div>
```

I would want

```
Link!
<b>Bold Text</b>
<div>A div!</div>
```

to be the output.

Is there any 'blacklist-based sanitizer' for Ruby?

Comment: Alternatively, would it be sufficient to use a print CSS that removes coloration and text-underline from all links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor variation on the Tin Man's answer, still using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org):

```
require 'nokogiri' # gem install nokogiri
doc = Nokogiri.HTML( my_html )
doc.css('a,blink,marquee').each do |el|
  el.replace( el.inner_html )
end
cleaned = doc.to_html
```

The two differences here are:

1. Using `css` over `search` to be slightly more specific about the selectors being used (though it offers no functional difference), but more importantly
2. By replacing with `inner_html` we preserve possible markup inside the link. For example, given the markup:

   ```html
   <p><a href="foo">Hi <b>Mom</b></a>!</p>
   ```

   then replacing with `.content` would produce:

   ```html
   <p>Hi Mom!</p>
   ```

   whereas replacing with `.inner_html` produces:

   ```html
   <p>Hi <b>Mom</b>!</p>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You want a HTML parser, such as [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org). It lets you walk through the document, searching for specific nodes ("tags") and do things to them:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<a href="link">Link!</a>
<b>Bold Text</b>
<div>A div!</div>
'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)

doc.search('a').each do |a|
  a.replace(a.content)
end

puts doc.to_html
```

Which results in:

```html
<html><body>Link!
<b>Bold Text</b>
<div>A div!</div>
</body></html>
```

Notice that Nokogiri did some fixups to the code, supplying the appropriate `<html>` and `<body>` tags. It doesn't have to, I could have told it to use and return a document fragment, but usually we let it do its thing.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned "elements" plural and "blacklist", you can do: `doc.search('a,script,…')` (for example) to select multiple element types to change at once.

Comment: Good point, though the results of replacing `<script>` tags with their content will be "icky", to use the professional term.

Comment: You're right, that's a terrible alternative. I had trouble thinking of another element that might be unwanted in PDF.

Comment: I'd like to see `<blink>` removed from PDFs. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.2 can do this out of the box. For older versions `gem 'rails-html-sanitizer'` is required

## white list only the supplied tags and attributes

```
white_list_sanitizer = Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.new
white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(@article.body, tags: %w(table tr td), attributes: %w(id class style))
```

or use Loofah's TargetScrubber

Rails::Html::TargetScrubber

Where PermitScrubber picks out tags and attributes to permit in sanitization, Rails::Html::TargetScrubber targets them for removal.

```
scrubber = Rails::Html::TargetScrubber.new
scrubber.tags = ['img']

html_fragment = Loofah.fragment('<a><img/ ></a>')
html_fragment.scrub!(scrubber)
html_fragment.to_s # => "<a></a>"
```

[Rails HTML sanitizer](https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer)

Comment: Note that `Rails::Html::TargetScrubber` strips the element by _replacing it with its contents_ (as required by OP). If you want to actually remove the whole element, you need to define a custom scrubber like this: `Loofah::Scrubber.new do |node| node.remove if REMOVE_TAGS.include?(node.name) end`

Answer (score 0):

```
html_without_links = remove_tags("<a href="link">Link!</a><b>Bold Text</b><div>A div!</div>",'a')
```

You can use the method above with the code below and you should get what you want.

```
require 'nokogiri'

def is_html?(text)
  stripped_text = Nokogiri::HTML(text).text.strip
  return !stripped_text.eql?(text)
end

def remove_tags(message_string,tag=nil)
  return message_string if message_string.blank? || tag.blank? || !is_html?(message_string)
  html_doc = Nokogiri.HTML(message_string)
  html_doc.search(tag).each do |a|
    a.replace(a.content)
  end

  html_doc.text
end
```